# Buffer tasks data with timeout

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, rabbitmq, task-parallel-library

I have a rather tricky question to solve. I have multiple (up to hundred or more) tasks, each of them produce a piece of data, say, string. These tasks can be spawn in every moment and there can be huge amount of them in one time and no at another. Each task must receive bool, indicating, whether is was completed correctly or not (that's important).

I want to implement some kind of buffer, to agregate data from tasks and flush it to external service, returning operation state (ok or fail). Also, my buffer must be flushed by timeout (to prevent waiting for new tasks to generate data for too long).

So far i tried to make some shared list of items. Tasks can add items to list and there is another task, checking timer or count of items in list and flushing them. But in this approach i can't tell status of flush operation to task, which is very bad for me.

I'll be gratefull for any approarch to solve my problem.

Comment: Have a look at Dataflow

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do tasks return bool (success/failure) or do they return something else, e.g. string? Also how do you create and run your tasks? Can you delay start?

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev tasks consume messages from rabbitmq, it's a service bus. They do some calculations and then flush results to DB. But when they do it separately, they make inserts too slow, so i want some kind of batching. So tasks need to return bool to service bus (ack message) and, thus, they need to receive insertion status from persister.

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy, one of the options is to send results back to RabbitMQ, obviously to different exchange/queue which can be consumed by another process, for example, windows service. It could aggregate results and flush them to db. Even if it cannot be done (in case of tech constraints), you need to have a queue to save big amount of messages aka task results.

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev i lack performance mostly because of slow inserts to db and batching inserts will make this part much, much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need to save result of each task to database/service, but you don't want to do it immediately.

There can be more than one solution to your problem, but it's difficult to come up with the best one, so I'll describe how I would have done it ... quickly.

A container for data you need to save/send.

```
public class TaskResultEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Result { get; set; }
}
```

A notifier which also runs the task for you. I assumed you can delay execution of tasks.

```
public class NotifyingTaskRunner
{
    public event EventHandler<TaskResultEventArgs> TaskCompleted;

    public void RunAndNotify(Task<bool> task)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            OnTaskCompleted(this, new TaskResultEventArgs { Result = t.Result });
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        task.Start();
    }

    protected virtual void OnTaskCompleted(object sender, TaskResultEventArgs e)
    {
        var h = TaskCompleted;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

A listener which can buffer and/or flush results (or you might want to delegate this to another class).

```
public class Listener
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<bool> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<bool>();

    public Listener(NotifyingTaskRunner runner)
    {
        runner.TaskCompleted += Flush;
    }

    public async void Flush(object sender, TaskResultEventArgs e)
    {
        // Enqueue status to flush everything later (or flush it immediately)
        _queue.Enqueue(e.Result);
    }
}
```

And this is how you can use everything together.

```
var runner = new NotifyingTaskRunner();
var listener = new Listener(runner);

var t1 = new Task<bool>(() => { return true; });
var t2 = new Task<bool>(() => { return false; });

runner.RunAndNotify(t1);
runner.RunAndNotify(t2);
```